# Vert.x EventBus handler as Flow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, vert.x, kotlin-flow

I'd like to consume events from the Vert.x event bus and provide them through a Kotlin Coroutine Flow.

However it looks like the Flow is immediately closed before anyone can send to the event bus address and no messages ever appear in it.

My code to produce the Flow:

```kotlin
fun assetCreated(): Flow<AssetsMutation.AssetCreated> =
        vertx.eventBus()
            .localConsumer<AssetsMutation.AssetCreated>(AssetsMutation.MESSAGE_BUS_ASSET_CREATED)
            .bodyStream()
            .toReceiveChannel(vertx)
            .receiveAsFlow()
}
```

What confuses me more is the documented example of `handleTemperatureStream` which has a comment at the end "the stream is now closed" without any indication on *why* it would be closed.

Comment: Where do you see that the flow is closed?

Comment: Using the browsers development tools I can see the `complete` message appearing on the websocket which according to what I understand about the code should only be sent once the flow is closed and won't produce any more items.

Comment: Can you share a larger example? The code above has no mention of websockets

Comment: The code in your question looks fine. I use the same in all of my vert.x projects. Maybe you can share some more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
suspend fun main() {
    val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
    vertx.setPeriodic(5000) {
     println("sending message on eventbus")
     vertx.eventBus().send("test", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
     println("message sent")
    }

    vertx.eventBus().localConsumer<String>("test")
     .toReceiveChannel(vertx)
     .receiveAsFlow()
     .onStart { println("start") }
     .onEmpty { println("empty") }
     .onCompletion { println("complete") }
     .collect { println(it.body()) }}
```

Works for me as expected - the flow is not closed - double check your code

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. It seems like the problem must lie with the graphql-java / graphql-kotlin-generator provided FlowSubscriptionExecutionStrategy or its configuration then...